# Data being drawn from core data is incorrect

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I have an app that stores data using `core data`. At one point data is retrieved and I can't seem to get it right. I am trying to get the value -5 as from the field **ObsObservationResult**.

In the `sqlite` browser I see this:

[image]

The value is stored as -5. The data from `core data` is retrieved using:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Observations"];
NSError *error = nil;
observationList = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

And

```
    NSUInteger obsResult = [[[observationList objectAtIndex:loop1] valueForKey: @"obsObservationResult"] integerValue];
```

sets ObsResult but when I look at the actual value retrieved I get something odd.

[image]

I have no idea why it does not show -5 as it id in the `sqlite` database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSUInteger` is an unsigned integer which does not support negative numbers. Use `NSInteger` instead. What you are seeing is the `NSUInteger` representation of -5.

Comment: Fantastic - how did I not see that U. Thank you.